# Multithreading with LAPACK 3.3 & above on MacOS 10.6 and 10.7

Tags: multithreading, macos, lapack, blas

I am trying to build and run a multi-thread program using openMP on MAC 10.6 and MAC 10.7
the program calls
zgelss and zgemm from multiple thread

I have compiled the LAPACK 3.4 and refBLAS

I compiled my program with following command

```
g++-4.2 main.cpp -o testProduct -L/Users/LAPACK/lapack-3.4.0/ -llapack3.4 \
        -lrefblas -L/Users/opt/gcc4.2/lib -lgfortran -fopenmp
```

The results of this program are not correct
where as when I compile the program with libraries provided by Apple it works fine on 10.7 but not 10.6

(MAC 10.7 have modified lapack 3.2.1) and (MAC 10.6 have modified lapack 3.1.1) --I guess

```
g++-4.2 main.cpp -o testProduct -framework accelerate -fopenmp
```

Can any one explain if LAPACK 3.4 and its corresponding BLAS is thread safe what could be the problem?